# Dagger 2 Singleton Component with RunTime SubComponent

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm building an application which uses Dagger 2.

So, my application component looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    // Exported for child-components.
    Application application ();

    final class Initializer {
        public static ApplicationComponent init (Application app) {
            return DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                    .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(app)).build();
        }

        private Initializer () {
        } // No instances.
    }


    ConnectorComponent plus(ConnectorModule module);

    ... injections

}
```

This is scoped with @Singleton, so it's unique for the app lifetime.
Then I have another component, which should be able to use all dependencies provided by the above component, but provide it's dependencies with a @PerActivity scope:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface PerActivity {}
```

And looks like this

```
@PerActivity
@Subcomponent(modules = ConnectorModule.class)
public interface ConnectorComponent  {

    ... injections
}
```

The problem is. How can I make sure the everything that is provided with @Singleton will be passed as Singletons on the dependencies to ConnectorModule? Another thing, how can I make sure that the method `plus` in ApplicationComponent will always add a new Module (the @PerActivity) that I want?

Last of all, can anybody think of a strategy to use this in all activites (which makes sense to be used with @PerAcitivity scope) and not having to call `plus` every time with a new ConnectorModule?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make sure the everything that is provided with @Singleton will be passed as Singletons on the dependencies to ConnectorModule?

Dagger will ensure that any `@Singleton`-annotated type or `@Provides` method in `ApplicationModule` will be provided only once during the lifetime of the `DaggerApplicationComponent` you build, even when a binding in `ConnectorComponent` uses it.

> how can I make sure that the method plus in ApplicationComponent will always add a new Module (the @PerActivity) that I want?

I'm not sure what you're asking here. When you call `plus`, you'll have to pass in an instance of `ConnectorModule` yourself.

> can anybody think of a strategy to use this in all activites (which makes sense to be used with @PerAcitivity scope) and not having to call plus every time with a new ConnectorModule?

Does `ConnectorModule` take arguments in its constructor? If not, you can leave it out of the `plus` method's arguments, and Dagger will construct one for you.

However, you still have to call the `plus` method in order to get an instance of the subcomponent for the activity. That's how you get the `@PerActivity` scope to work: there's an instance of `ConnectorComponent`, and that scope is tied to the lifetime of that instance.